Is it possible to retrieve (scrap) reels hidden in the feed using graphql (query_hash)?
I have a question about retrive/scraping videos (reels) on Instagram, specifically those that are hidden by default in a user's main feed.
The link that looks like this:
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=e769aa130647d2354c40ea6a439bfc08&variables={"id":[id],"first":12}
allows me to retrieve the feed. However, the user can hide the selected reels in the feed so that they are only available in the 'Reels' tab of the user's account page. Attempting to call the above query does not return me these hidden reels (even though chronologically they should be returned in this query)
The "Reels" tab is accessible from the anonymous account, so no login is required, but I can't find a way to retrieve them. Perhaps there is a separate hash for this?
I also tried the hash 60b755363b5c230111347a7a4e242001 but without success
